# Spring with cucumber tests not found by maven surfire or failsafe

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, cucumber

I have project that runs integration tests apart from my main application. The tests are successfully run by IntelliJ but maven plugin isn't recognizing any tests. It is recognizing the BackendTests file.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/BackendTests.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/BackendTests.java</include>
                </includes>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

These are my other dependencies in pom.xml:

```
        <!-- Spring boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Cucumber -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

That is my BackendTests file:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue = {"backendtests.step", "backendtests.table", "backendtests.config"}
)
public class BackendTests {
}
```

I have config directory with two files: AbstractIntegrationTest and SpringCucumberConfiguration.

```
@SpringBootTest
public class AbstractIntegrationTest {
}

.............

@CucumberContextConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Application.class, AbstractIntegrationTest.class}, loader = SpringBootContextLoader.class)
public class SpringCucumberConfiguration {
}
```

And my steps are in step.definitions folder. Every step extends AbstractionIntegration test file. When I change `<include>**/BackendTests.java</include>` to `<include>**/Gibberish.java</include>` for example I don't see nothing about tests in the console when I run mvn clean install command. But if the filename is correct `<include>**/BackendTests.java</include>`, I see:

[image]

Comment: Fixed with: `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>`